# How to plot Fastai loss function after each learning cycle

Tags: plot, pytorch, loss-function, fast-ai

https://github.com/BorutFlis/predictor/blob/master/soccer_predictor.ipynb

The problem is available in the notebook above.

```
learn.recorder.plot_loss()
```

I use this command and the image(check notebook) plots the validation loss by every cycle of learning, while it plots a lot more data from the train-set loss. Can I change this somehow so that the train loss will only be plotted after each cycle?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a callback during loading learner.
The callback `ShowGraph` can record the training and validation loss graph.
you can customize the output plot e.g. After each epoch or after completion of training.

**Method :**
Load learner:

```
learn = models.classifier_learner(data, models.densenet121, callback_fns=[ShowGraph])
```

you can add more `callbacks` here:
Then Add this callback and put `learner` to get the plot.

```
callbacks = [SaveModelCallback(learn, monitor=['val_loss', 
            'cdice'],mode='min',name='best_model'), ShowGraph(learn),
EarlyStoppingCallback(learn, min_delta=1e-5, patience=5)]
```